# Export variable or register to file

Tags: vim

I'm trying to export a variable to a file:

To simplify what I'm doing right now, I use the variable `@"` which contains the content of the current register :

```
function! CopyVar()
  call system("printf '%s' '".@"."' > /tmp/varfile")
endfunction
nnoremap <Leader>y :call CopyVar()<cr>
```

This works fine, but doesn't work if the variable contains single quotes for example.

If the input is for example `" hi '` , the command fails with `E484: Can't open file /tmp/v7IzDCI/74`

I think I could `escape` the `@"` (because if `'` single quotes are present, the command will fail), however, I'm not sure it is the best method to export a variable to a file.

How can I do it to guarantee that it will work with any input (with quotes, multilines and other special characters) ?

I know that you can use the system clipboard, it's not what I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: "it's not what I'm trying to achieve here" so… what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to export the full content of a variable to a file. So that I can reuse it from outside of vim with other programs

Comment: And you don't use the clipboard because?

Comment: @romainl because I'm over ssh and am not allowed to install an xserver

Comment: That's a valid reason but… your workflow is broken if you need to paste stuff over the wire.

Answer (score 3):

That is what `shellescape()` is for. BTW for better quoting, I would write your function like this:

```
function! CopyVar()
  let cmd="printf '%s'". shellescape(@") . " > /tmp/varfile"
  call system(cmd)
endfunction
nnoremap <Leader>y :call CopyVar()<cr>
```

However, your solution looks overly complex, by adding some shell quotation to the complex VimL quotation. That is not needed. I would rather do it differently:

```
:redir! > /tmp/varfile | sil exe 'echo @"' |redir end
```

This adds an extra leading blank line at the beginning, but you could remove this afterwards using sed or something.

Or even better, use the `writefile()` function:

```
nnoremap <Leader>y :call writefile(split(@", '\n'), '/tmp/varfile')
```

Comment: It now doesn't trigger an error, however, new lines are replaced by \newline , and `%s` is replaced by '' (try copying the text of the function itself with `<Leader>y`)

Comment: WFM. However your code looks overly complex. How about something like this: `:redir! > /tmp/varfile | exe 'echo @"' |redir end` This adds an extra empty line at the beginning of the file, but that could be deleted afterwards

Answer (score 0):

`@"` is a register, not a variable.

You can use a substitution to clean up your text:

```
let foo = substitute(getreg('"'), "'", "\"", "g")
```

before the "write" step.

I'll let you figure out what patterns you need to clean up.

Comment: This replaces `'` by `"` which is not wanted. I'v tried to do  `substitute(getreg('"'), "'", "\\\\'", "g")` which correctly does the replacement, however the printf still fails

Answer (score 0):

Using redir is probably the most robust solution

```
function! CopyVar()
  redir! > /tmp/varfile | sil exe 'echo @"' |redir end
  call system ("sed '1d' /tmp/varfile > /tmp/tmpvarfile; mv /tmp/tmpvarfile /tmp/varfile")
endfunction
nnoremap <Leader>y :call CopyVar()<cr>
```

It works with any characters. The second part is needed because the redirection will add an additional newline which is not wanted, hence the sed command.